# Turn XML with XSLT to aHTML order Table

Tags: html, xml, xslt

i need yout help. I'm struggle with XSLT: I have for example an XML file like this:

```
<Adresses>
<Person id="1">
  <Name>Bott</Name>
  <Vorname>Nils</Vorname>
</Person>

<Person id="2">
  <Name>Hubert</Name>
  <Vorname>Hubertus</Vorname>
</Person>

<Person id="3">
  <Name>Large</Name>
  <Vorname>Lars</Vorname>
</Person>

<Numbers>
  <number>
    <id>1</id>
    <tel>12354</tel>
  </number>
  <number>
    <id>3</id>
    <tel>32354</tel>
  </number>
  <number>
    <id>2</id>
    <tel>22354</tel>
  </number>
</Numbers>

</Adresses>
```

And i have to transform to a order HTML Table.
The HTML Table should look like folowwing (Ordering after ID):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Vorname</th>
    <th>Tel</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Bott</th>
    <th>Nils</th>
    <th>12354</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My Problem is i don't know how to ckeck: Choose the number where Peron.id = number.id .... It would be realy great if someone could give me a full example for this problem. At web search it is always not so complicated in the tutorials ;-( .... I'm learning XSLT and just know some rules like apply-templates match="Person" .... but how is it possible in such a statement to call a other template wich select the coorect number?

I try to start with that:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:for-each select="Adresses/Person">
  <xsl:call-template name="curPos">
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="Vorname"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="curPos" match="Person">
 <xsl:value-of select="position()"/><br> </br>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the following XSLT 2.0 solution for you:

```
<xsl:template name="makeTable">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Vorname</th>
        <th>Tel</th>
    </tr>        
    <xsl:for-each select="/Adresses/Person">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Vorname"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../Numbers/number[id = current()/@id]/tel"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>    
  </table>   
</xsl:template>
```

Now, for the explanation as far as I understand the problem you have is finding the correct XPath expression for selecting the correct telephone number. The most important code snipped in this case is this line:

```
<td>
  <xsl:value-of select="../Numbers/number[id = current()/@id]/tel"/>
</td>
```

In XSLT 2.0 - I'm not sure about XSLT 1.0 - you can refer to the current loop element with the `current()` function in an XPath.
To select the telephone number I filter for the number on the condition of its `id` being equal to the current loop elements attribute `id` and then getting this node's child `tel` to get the actual number.

Comment: If there's a problem with current (), you can set the value in a variable with <xsl:variable name='current_id' select='@id'/> and then select with '../Numbers/number[id=$current_id]/tel'.

Comment: There is no problem with `current()`. There **is** a problem with named template that isn't called.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I do not see a point in posting my complete source code, when this part answers the question quite fine. You may notice that the html body is missing aswell.

Comment: @Mike You are probably right a variable might have been better

Comment: I don't see the point of using a named template in the first place. I find your answer confusing - and I am not exactly a beginner like OP.

Answer (score 2):

> My Problem is i don't know how to ckeck: Choose the number where
>   Peron.id = number.id ....

That's exactly what **[keys](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** are for:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="num" match="number" use="id" />

<xsl:template match="/Adresses">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Vorname</th>
                    <th>Tel</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="Person">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Vorname"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="key('num', @id)/tel"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that your table structure assumes each person has only one phone number (as in your example). However, the XML structure suggests there is a one-to-many relationship between persons and phone numbers, so you might want to consider changing:

```
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('num', @id)/tel"/>
</td>
```

to:

```
<td>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('num', @id)">
        <xsl:value-of select="tel"/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</td>
```